# What 1-Form Satisfies this Property?

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds, smooth-manifolds, differential-forms

**Question**

Give an example of a 1-form $\alpha \in \Omega ^1(\mathbb{R}^3)$ with the property that $\alpha \wedge d\alpha = dx\wedge dy\wedge dz$.

**Attempt**

If we take $\alpha=fdx+gdy+hdz$,

then, $d\alpha=(\frac{\partial h}{\partial y}-\frac{\partial g}{\partial z})dy\wedge dz+(\frac{\partial g}{\partial x}-\frac{\partial f}{\partial y})dx\wedge dy+(\frac{\partial f}{\partial z}-\frac{\partial h}{\partial x})dz\wedge dx$.

This means,

$\alpha \wedge d\alpha = [f(\frac{\partial h}{\partial y}-\frac{\partial g}{\partial z})+g(\frac{\partial f}{\partial z}-\frac{\partial h}{\partial x})+h(\frac{\partial g}{\partial x}-\frac{\partial f}{\partial y})]dx\wedge dy\wedge dz$.

However, I don’t seem to know what $f,g$ and $h$ should be so that the sum of terms in the square brackets would give me 1.

Your help would be appreciated.

Comment: Trial and error. Start with the simplest ones, say constant ones. When it doesn’t work, try the next simplest, say linear, etc.

Comment: It may help to identify your sum of terms with $F \cdot \text{curl}(F)$, where $F = (f,g,h)$.

Comment: notice that if you take $f,g,h$ all constant, then you’ll get $0$. The next thing to try is to keep two of them constant, and one of them a linear function; it turns out this can be done.

Comment: The equality $\alpha \wedge d\alpha = dx \wedge (dy \wedge dz)$ suggests that you can look for a 1-form of the form $\alpha = dx + \beta$, with $d\beta = dy\wedge dz$ and $\beta \wedge d\beta = 0$.
Then, $\beta = ydz$, or $\beta = -zdy$, or even $\beta = \frac{1}{2}(ydz - zdy)$, work

Comment: @peek-a-boo I kept two constant and one linear ($f=2,g=-1,h=x$). Turns out I got the required result. Thanks.

Comment: even simpler: $\alpha=x\,dy+dz$, i.e you can set one of them to be $0$.

Comment: @peek-a-boo I need some clarity here. Suppose I want to find $d\alpha$ (from scratch), given $\alpha=xdy+dz$, then I will have to differentiate $x$ partially wrt $x$ and “attach” $dx\wedge dy$ to the result. Since I have a constant attached to $dz$, how am I supposed to differentiate the constant? (I want to see if working with this from scratch will get me the desired result, rather than plugging in the values into the equation I derived.

Comment: $\alpha=x\,dy+dz$ implies $d\alpha= dx\wedge dy+ d(dz)=dx\wedge dy+0=dx\wedge dy$. Or simply, the derivative of a constant is $0$, so that’s why there’s no more terms involving $z$.

Comment: @peek-a-boo Oh, now I see where I mixed things up.